# Simple Complex ODEs in Matrix Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus

We know that complex numbers can be written as:
$$a+ib\equiv\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\ b& a \end{pmatrix}$$

in matrix form. Suppose we want to solve the differential equation: 
$$f'(x)+if(x)=0$$
The solution is $f(x)=c e^{-ix}$. Suppose that instead, we want to solve this equation by writing the above equation in a matrix form, i.e.
$$f'(x)+if(x)\equiv \begin{pmatrix}f'(x)&-f(x)\\ f(x)& f'(x) \end{pmatrix}$$ 
My question is: Is it possible to solve this equation and, in general, other possibly non-linear ODE's using the matrix representation?

Thanks, Michał

Comment: Not necessarily complex numbers-y, but this technique is used for turning second order PDEs into first order, e.g. the two way wave equation into the one way wave equation.

Comment: You seem to be presuming that $f,f'$ are purely real, but this would force $c=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Well spotted, this was indeed the problem with my understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are also complex numbers. So if $f(x)=g(x)+ih(x)$, then you can write
$$f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}g(x)&-h(x)\\h(x)&g(x)\end{bmatrix},$$
so your differential equation becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}g'(x)&-h'(x)\\h'(x)&g'(x)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}g(x)&-h(x)\\h(x)&g(x)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
You can solve this; it is a coupled set of differential equations
$$g'(x)-h(x)=0; h'(x)+g(x)=0,$$
which can become a second order differential equation:
$$g''(x)+g(x)=0$$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!